# AE JavaScript finding Layer Object when none is given

Tags: javascript, after-effects

Attempting to create a 3D shape with children that rotates at an accelerating pace from 0 to 3 seconds, I used the following script

```
if (time < 3)
  Math.pow(time, 2)*30;
```

That gave me the following error

> After Effects warning: Object of type Layer found where a Number,
>   Array, or Property is needed
>
> Expression disabled.
>
> Error occured at line 0.
>
> Comp: 'Main'
>
> Layer: 15 ('Blue')
>
> Property: 'Y Rotation'

Comp name, layer name and property name are all valid. They point to the property I was trying to edit.
However, what puzzles me is that I fixed that by using the following code.

```
ctime = time;
if (ctime < 3)
  Math.pow(ctime, 2)*30;
```

The code is now working as intended, and I have no idea why.

Comment: Post your full code, the culprit isn't in sight. Also you don't seem to be using the result of `Math.pow`.

Comment: @Ultimater that is the full code. This is an expression snipplet used in After Effects, which uses the return value of the final line as the input for whichever object the scipt is written for, which in this case is the Y-rotation of a layer named Blue.

Comment: @Ultimater I'm half convinced the issue has something to do with AE (or its implementation of JS), hence the tag and title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the condition is false, the two would be different since there would be no last statement to use.
Try: `(time < 3)?Math.pow(time, 2)*30:time;`

Comment: Just tested and I can confirm AE was using ctime=time; as the value for the 2nd code if the if clause failed. Will be using the code with else 0; for readability. Thanks. Also, now I feel stupid.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.pow(time^2*30);` is simply bad code. `Math.pow` expects two arguments and you only gave it one. Also `^` is a bitwise operator, there is no power raising operator in JavaScript, you need to use Math.pow.